# CMake - setting file permissions after installation (java)

Tags: java, cmake

I had a question involving setting permissions using CMake.  Right now I am currently modifying CMake files that build our Java code using an Ant script.  We want to convert our Java code to CMake so we can make use of Build Avoidance.  After reading the CMake documentation, it seems like we can compile and install our Java packages, but the install_jar() command does not allow us to set permissions like the install command does.

I'm assuming we want to use the install_jar command so we can make use of the find_jar command when compiling against dependencies, so I would like to keep the install_jar command.  Is there some sort of chmod command for CMake, or some best practices way for setting the installed files permissions after they have been installed?

Thanks,

Comment: Just curious to know why move from ant to cmake? If you are really looking for an improved build environment gradel, ivy etc may be good choice.

Comment: We have a fairly complex system.  Most of which contains C++ code.  Java is a small part of the build and CMake is our main build utility that we use to perform developer/Nightly builds through Jenkins.  It seemed easier integrating our Java builds into CMake with the new CMake Java enhancements.  If there is some build utility for Java that integrates nicely with CMake, I'm all ears.

Comment: Did you write to CMake dev team?

Comment: I have not, I'll go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `install_jar()` definition is, basically, just `install()` call:

```
function(INSTALL_JAR _TARGET_NAME _DESTINATION)
    get_property(__FILES
        TARGET ${_TARGET_NAME}
        PROPERTY INSTALL_FILES
    )

    if (__FILES)
        install(FILES ${__FILES}
                DESTINATION ${_DESTINATION}
        )
    else (__FILES)
        message(SEND_ERROR "The target ${_TARGET_NAME} is not known in this scope.")
    endif (__FILES)
endfunction(INSTALL_JAR _TARGET_NAME _DESTINATION)
```

So you can just write your own `install_jar_with_args()` and add `PERMISSIONS` keyword to the `install()` call.

Probably, this problem needs to be reported to CMake devs.